# Terraform add existing security group to new auto scaling ec2 group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, autoscaling

I want to add an existing Security Group defined in the VPC to an EC2 Auto Scaling Group.
There is no LB defined. This example creates a single EC2 instance for now.

Terraform documentation shows that this is possible for EC2 instances using sg_attachment

```
resource "aws_network_interface_sg_attachment" "bastion" {
  security_group_id    = var.sg_id
  network_interface_id = aws_autoscaling_group.bastion.primary_network_interface_id
}
```

But I get the following error, probably because I'm using Auto-scaling groups instead:

> Error: Unsupported attribute
>
> on ......\modules\ec2_auto_scaling_group\bastion.tf line 51, in
>   resource "aws_network_interface_sg_attachment" "bastion":   51:
>   network_interface_id =
>   aws_autoscaling_group.bastion.primary_network_interface_id
>
> This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
>   "primary_network_interface_id".

I've seen the autoscaling group attachment - https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_attachment.html

But this doesn't refer to security groups at all.

Of course - I could implicitly specify a new security group with all the same rules, or just declare an ec2 instance instead. But when creating an autoscaling group on the console - you get the option to import existing Security groups. So I'd like to think that terraform has an equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I've overlooked previous settings:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "bastion" {
  # Launch configuration can't be updated, (provisioning)
  # in order to update the resource will be destroyed and rebuilt

  name_prefix = var.bastion_name_prefix

  image_id = data.aws_ami.RHEL_77.id 
  instance_type = var.bastion_instance_type
  key_name = aws_key_pair.bastion.key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  enable_monitoring = false
  security_groups = [var.vpc_main_sg_id,aws_security_group.bastion.id]

  lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Adding a security group to aws_launch_configuration, fixed the issue.

Comment: All AutoScaling Groups need either a launch configuration or launch template to provide the instance settings.  I'd recommend looking into using a launch template since it is required for using all the newer autoscaling features